# Событие change срабатывает два раза

Tags: javascript, android, select, multiple

Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?
Система: Android
Браузер: Chrome Mobile
Элемент: Select[type=multiple]
На select висит обработчик onchange.

Выбираю select, появляется окошко выбора options.
Выбираю только один option.
Нажимаю ОК - срабатывает событие change.

Нажимаю в любое другое место, снова срабатывает событие change.
Как от этого избавиться?

Причем, если выбрано несколько options, то событие срабатывает только раз, при нажатии на ОК. Так по идее и должно быть.

Comment: Проверить решение в других браузерах, мобильных, декстопных. Если ошибка есть. То вам нужно просмотреть весь код. По возможности предоставить его. Может где-то у вас два change

Comment: Еще такое бывает из за [всплытия](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling)

Comment: Код в студию пожалуйста.